# Cannot find name 'apply'.ts(2304) on function

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I cannot persuade TS to use apply method on function :/

Using `merge` from lodash

```
merge<PropertyValidationList, PropertyValidationList>.apply(merge, lists);
```

type definition of merge

```
merge<TObject, TSource>(object: TObject, source: TSource): TObject & TSource;
merge<TObject, TSource1, TSource2>(object: TObject, source1: TSource1, source2: TSource2): TObject & TSource1 & TSource2;

etc..
```

getting error:

```
Cannot find name 'apply'.ts(2304)
```

I've tryied:

```
(merge<PropertyValidationList, PropertyValidationList>).apply(merge, lists);
(merge as typeof merge<PropertyValidationList, PropertyValidationList>).apply(merge, lists);
merge.apply<PropertyValidationList, PropertyValidationList>(merge, lists);
etc..
```

googled stuff.. nothing helped

Bypassed for now with ugly fix

```
const propertyList: PropertyValidationList = (merge as any).apply(merge, lists);
```

[Minimal reproducible example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgDIHsAicDOALAZTDjGAWQG8AoZW5AegCpGa7lHkAlCBAVyhzAAbhAA2AT2QBbaAHMIOZOgDuIZHBAATZKDzRgkbRBC8ZUOACNRKAA5R0N6KQVKYyHOn5JWdDugsAVjxgiqBg6MhgesiaCqQgJMDoav5BCGAANO4A1sA2NqCy7p5QSMh2Dk7ALlEkyFAK6KIiPrQc4cgABrxaEDCgEJqdAHTIAIJQ5pIa2jaicKBKgcHl9o5QzopwDdJyg-U8-IIiEsOt7MgA8lHQS2kh6lrIQnCivChg4o5bO%20gik8BNLE1BZpjhBLIQDJwKMCCUyqlgjhzhxtig4PlRNVtDB7FJkNYYGBIhEoMBZHgwLDeBYcBAAI7vcDFLwuP7QZRkyCrSobcQo9Tg8lQ4wPdBuOwQIRJXiKDysnBnNjsAXMABy6EgAC5mMgACp4YCKGRRdDaKS8YiQRSdRHpEYogUAAQQJAgsnQUEkl2W6WdNm2cHxduJBpQsRw8USyTuwSVbA4ToD5nxAG15aUFABdfXRDMI30heO%20ZBOhpgfggRTcCtQKtdEMO5WJiAADyDcwgjubz22yFl0EUAF5KALaAByTQkODjrXIVMUZDjgdQWdLizbEAQcTj5AAXyyi%20XdNXc-HuMGu73WYFe4A3N2E72oOp5MPRz2J1PiGuF0u4PIa4AMwAGz7oe-6AXOAAsAAM%2043j296PiWAD6wxmPIAAUK44FkAEKAAlA%20Pb0PQyBDgAfJQS7fjOc5-se0BruOG51tu45ZOOBHAWBB40Uxp5LhemicZBEBrnBCH7ii9CtJhEAADx6j69xZHqcKspRWEhnOKmFlk%20YQHpmmZoRemqSsABk%20qmUgJF0EwLA9k6dIoOhCmyfJezKZZ6TqXZEAAIwBfCEAAEzabp%20p%20ZkLKZkFJlhSF8VIOFSWsuF5kxYWyA2RpyV5bZYXhQ5tBOc6bnIB5exeWwCm%20QZxWsilBWZaFrJAVFhYWU1RmJc1CWGSVGWZuFw2daNSBAdl%20n3EVbUJQtgXhctYVAWVDDMJVEDuRhtXNnJ9U%20XNwQdUNg1ped03XRA0HdfcvVqalwVTcFE1jW940vUBb1AR9SDQW90GzbFa0teDY2Q9N0N3ZtFUuVVNVQPIdV0ApOk9Y84hZMMeOanoUATLIOBzho4iplm2Xkw%20yFUAgySRrsKPGWgWC4IQVpkKm44KeOOYjlhePDNsJNzrFlOERR1HUGwZHIPAuQgEUwBSJ20Jc8krQM1WxINDgvCiMSI4UMhbCi4qMCegAoogeCYwE0tXIWItCpCWH64bcWpIRxGtOWlYHAbRu01QYdtjYnrEp8jjIAAaq8gIkJ6BDiCA5CCy8ohkyA4hS1RkRQO8yAAD7uGAZLKw%20EdR5EXwoAnWLfkkIBjDgacZ8gAAKeJGkpFfF2XkaV7IlHV62kcbHXseN0n4RE%2036cUcgWFZznedO7PzfJG3Hfj5P0f1-Hiffp6y9b8nUCp0vZcX-Pu-p-vtcxw3J-RiA3A4JHVYoCbvZN3OCw6AmgQA0PuJ%20U8X7dzWE4cQd8W7L0XEXawpNj5N0vpTLI%20sK5kFIMkOcw9CjgKoDXSBR8e68k%20PA5IqAjTGy4DwT0mhFKEOVlkLu2xSCvEUhQ9YVC354JAJRMeJCJ7P3ITAvk1CQC0MjO%20XhsDpGyOJGXBRUiBEt2UZTB8oiD4Kx6OkBBFQ%20HiAABIcywsY2BBCcFsOQMLOAQIDCgFeBwlMqDWGyEljYkeH4Di1jUKmKxfJcZ40cZoZxCRRBuKDDgLMwwGj-DpFhQiwwAjoFAFhccqFxx%20z3OHMRU8YAGMETyEx0isJYjkXONR-D0GCOUXhexYSUaoJiSaQcikX7ijKbA8x%20BKLZVqXAjRMZZYEjoe%20SpkydC6w0EgHpEwphSwAPwTLkcgBiVSQhZgcqweWOsmbBM%20Mo5eDVhlKLoaE4YFzRkyLoZREWmJxBYQUlkbZOA-a0EOcSY54hTkjgxsLD5Xz-GB3GbQZBCgGJZgyP7OIZJDH4KXJxVows-laL%20f0%202DjWmEUQsQvcQA)

```
interface LoDashStatic {
    /**
     * Recursively merges own and inherited enumerable properties of source
     * objects into the destination object, skipping source properties that resolve
     * to `undefined`. Array and plain object properties are merged recursively.
     * Other objects and value types are overridden by assignment. Source objects
     * are applied from left to right. Subsequent sources overwrite property
     * assignments of previous sources.
     *
     * **Note:** This method mutates `object`.
     *
     * @category Object
     * @param object The destination object.
     * @param [sources] The source objects.
     * @returns Returns `object`.
     * @example
     *
     * var users = {
     *   'data': [{ 'user': 'barney' }, { 'user': 'fred' }]
     * };
     *
     * var ages = {
     *   'data': [{ 'age': 36 }, { 'age': 40 }]
     * };
     *
     * _.merge(users, ages);
     * // => { 'data': [{ 'user': 'barney', 'age': 36 }, { 'user': 'fred', 'age': 40 }] }
     */
    merge<TObject, TSource>(object: TObject, source: TSource): TObject & TSource;
    /**
     * @see _.merge
     */
    merge<TObject, TSource1, TSource2>(object: TObject, source1: TSource1, source2: TSource2): TObject & TSource1 & TSource2;
    /**
     * @see _.merge
     */
    merge<TObject, TSource1, TSource2, TSource3>(object: TObject, source1: TSource1, source2: TSource2, source3: TSource3): TObject & TSource1 & TSource2 & TSource3;
    /**
     * @see _.merge
     */
    merge<TObject, TSource1, TSource2, TSource3, TSource4>(object: TObject, source1: TSource1, source2: TSource2, source3: TSource3, source4: TSource4): TObject & TSource1 & TSource2 & TSource3 & TSource4;
    /**
     * @see _.merge
     */
    merge(object: any, ...otherArgs: any[]): any;
};

const merge: LoDashStatic['merge'] = (...args: Object[]) => {
    // faking implementation
    const result = {};
    args.forEach(obj => Object.assign(result, obj));
    return result;
}


export type ValidatorSync = (val: any) => true | string;
export type ValidationAsync = Promise<true | string>;
export type ValidatorAsync = (val: any) => ValidationAsync;
export type Validator = ValidatorSync | ValidatorAsync;
export type ValidationResponse = { valid: boolean };
export type PropertyValidation = { rules: Validator[], restriction: string };
export type PropertyValidationList = Record<string, Partial<PropertyValidation>>;
export type PropertyValidationLists = PropertyValidationList | PropertyValidationList[];

export function propertyHash(property: string, ...additinalParams: string[]): string {
  return [property, ...additinalParams].reverse().join('_');
}

export function propertyValidation(lists: PropertyValidationLists, ...args: Parameters<typeof propertyHash>): PropertyValidation {
  lists = (lists instanceof Array) ? lists : [lists];
  
  // const propertyList = merge<PropertyValidationList, ...PropertyValidationList>.apply(merge, lists);
  const propertyList = merge(...lists);
  return {
    rules: [],
    restriction: '',
    ...propertyList[propertyHash(...args)]
  };
}
```

Comment: Could you do a full [mre] please? Both here and [on the TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play)? At a minimum: What's `lists`? An example with an element or two would help.

Comment: Separately: Have you tried spread instead? `merge(...lists)`.

Comment: @t-j-crowder very nice idea :D but somehow I need to specify that `...list`, getting:
`
(parameter) lists: PropertyValidationList[]
A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter.ts(2556)
`
I am going to made that reproducible example in playground.

Comment: Well it seems that [changing the definition](https://tsplay.dev/N5L5Bw) of `merge` works. Maybe I will see if I can update the typings of lodash!